# Understanding a basic Swift compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I understand why this produces a compiler error:

```
let initialProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value:42)
let sideEffectProducer = initialProducer.on(next: { (answer: Int) in
  return _
})
```

The error is

> Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> _' to expected argument type
>   '(Int -> ())?'

So the `next` parameter takes a closure with an `Int` parameter that returns `Void` whilst we're returning `_`

But why does this compile fine:

```
let initialProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value:42)
let sideEffectProducer = initialProducer.on(next: { (answer: Int) in
  return ""
})
```

we're returning a `String`, not `Void` so why does the compiler not complain?

Comment: I'm curious as well. Hoping maybe @matt can explain...?

Comment: The input parameter is a function that returns `something` (`->()`).  It knows that the void function does not return `something`, so it complains.  But the second function returns `something`, a string.  So that passes the parameter check.  It's on you to make the return be something that you want it to be.

Comment: `(Int) -> ()` is a closure that takes an `Int` and returns `Void`, isn't it? http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/11/swift-vs-void/. Is `Void` not the same as 'nothing'? I can also comment out the return altogether and it compiles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` isn't *nothing*.  It is a *pattern*, or a part of a pattern that can match anything.  It can also be used in an assignment statement to show that you don't care about the result.

```
_ = foo()  // Ignore result returned from foo
```

In your closure, if you want to return *nothing*, then either:

```
return
```

or omit the return altogether if you're at the end of the closure.

If you return `_`, Swift cannot figure out the signature of your closure.  You can demonstrate that by doing:

```
let bar = { return _ }  // Unable to infer closure return type in current context
```

If you remove the `_`, it compiles fine since `bar` becomes a `() -> ()`.

Swift could have given you a better error message like it does if you try to return `_` from a function:

```
func foo() {
    return _  // '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment
}
```

---

So, why does `return ""` work?  Here's a clue.

There are some apparent oddness around single-line closures.  Consider the following example which is similar to yours:

```
func doit(handler: (Int) -> ()) {
    handler(17)
    print("doit is done")
}

doit() { (answer: Int) in
    //print(answer + 1)
    return ""
}
```

Running this produces the output:

> doit is done

So, like your example `doit` is expecting a `(Int) -> ()` closure, but we're passing a `(Int) -> String` closure.  And it works...

But, if you un-comment the `print(answer + 1)` line, the `return ""` then results in the error:

> Unexpected non-void return in void function

Comment: Thanks... but `(Int -> ())` means a closure that returns `Void`, doesn't it? How come returning a `String` is not a compiler error in that case? See my example above...

Comment: I don't have the full answer, but see my edit for a clue to what's going on.